# Node application running at IP and port, how to link to URL

Tags: node.js, express, server, vps

I have a node express application running on a VPS, and accessible via a public IP and port number.

I have bought a domain name.

How can I direct my domain name to my node app?

Server is running Node.js version v0.10.42

Comment: best not to expose your ip address on the web, you can anonymize it or just suffice to say that you have a public ip and port

Comment: Which version of node?

Comment: @dubes Thanks - updated

Comment: @dubes - That's silly that a public IP address is any kind of a secret.  It's public by its very nature.  It is not a secret in any way.  And, as soon as it is hooked to a domain, anyone whom you spread the domain to can just look up the corresponding IP address in DNS.

Comment: This question is about DNS configuration, not about the programming topics of stack overflow and thus is off-topic here - voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I was taking him for a walk, and you spoiled the surprise at the end...

Comment: @jfriend00 you are right, I fired my comment without any thought, gut reaction to seeing information which should not necessarily be shared.

Comment: Long story short, please don't waste people's time, it's not nice - read [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont want to run your app as root for security reasons, and the port 80 is reserved for the super user so, i recommend to run your app as always (express uses port 3000) and then use nginx to make a reverse proxy.

1.- The request comes on the port 80.

2.- nginx reads the header and knows where to redirect that based on the domain configured.

3.- the nodejs app recieves the request on the app port (maybe 3000) and makes a response.

4.- nginx redirects the response to the client.

I can add a configuration file for nginx if you need :D.

Comment: Thanks so much, this got me going in the right direction, and I have literally spent hours and hours and hours on it!!
I was wondering if you could take a quick look at my config file

Comment: nginx.conf:
```
user  asykes;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
worker_rlimit_nofile 20480;

events {
    worker_connections 5120; # increase for busier servers
    use epoll; # you should use epoll here for Linux kernels 2.6.x
}


http{
    include "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*";
}
```


sites-available/sentiment-sweep.conf
```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name sentiment-sweep.com;

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
  }
}
```

Comment: Currently, all domains on my server now redirect to the node app running at :3000 I need it to only be just the one domain to redirect to this app.

Ideally everything else should redirect to Apache (running on :8081), but I can't for the life of me get this to work :( Any ideas? Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You would need a DNS service to map your host name to your static ip. Refer to this thread for more details: https://serverfault.com/questions/148987/how-can-i-map-my-servers-domain-to-my-ip-address

Mostly and DNS service provider will be able to help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a nodejs or express specific issue or question. How to relate a DNS to an IP is specific to the provider of the DNS record you bought. For example if you bougth the DNS record to GoDaddy you have to use its [administration panel](https://www.godaddy.com/es/help/administrar-dns-para-tus-nombres-de-dominio-680) for that purposes and so on. Read the documentation on the page of the company you bought the DNS domain record.